# ¿Por qué mi List en java me repite el resultado?

Tags: java, lista, java-ee

estoy teniendo un pequeño inconveniente con un método que realice en java, para traer simplemente dos datos y cargarlo en un jcombobox (como información adicional lo estoy realizando en MVC - modelo, vista, controlador). Todo bien en la lógica pero no entiendo porque me trae un dato solamente y repetido. Les paso el codigo de la clase que esta en **tipoUsuarioDao** y se llama **cargarTipoUsuario** el cual me genera una lista que recibe mi controlador llamado **comboTipoUsu**

Metodo **cargarTipoUsuario**

```
public List cargarTipoUsuario(){
        List<tipoUsuarios> listaTipoUser = new ArrayList();
        String sql = "SELECT `IDTIPO_USUARIO`, `DESC_TIPO_USUARIO` FROM `tipo_usuario`";
        try {
            con = cn.getConexion();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                tipoUs.setIdTipoUsuario(rs.getInt("IDTIPO_USUARIO"));
//                System.out.println(rs.getInt("IDTIPO_USUARIO"));
                tipoUs.setDescripcionTipoUsuario(rs.getString("DESC_TIPO_USUARIO"));
//                System.out.println(rs.getString("DESC_TIPO_USUARIO"));
                listaTipoUser.add(tipoUs);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        }finally{
            cn.desconectar();
        }
        return listaTipoUser;
    }
```

Controlador **comboTipoUsu**

```
public void comboTipoUsu(){
        frmUsu.cbTipoUsuario.removeAllItems();
        String datos;
        List<tipoUsuarios> lista = tipoUsuDao.cargarTipoUsuario();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                datos = lista.get(i).getDescripcionTipoUsuario();
//                System.out.println(i +" "+datos);
                frmUsu.cbTipoUsuario.addItem(datos);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        }
        
    }
```

Y el resultado que me tira en el combo es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me trae dos veces *operador*

Comment: ya revisastes que en la tabla tipo_usuario tengas solo un operador? y no se encuentren 2

Comment: @HeynerMartinez si lo he revisado amigo, y hay dos datos los cuales son operador y administrador

Comment: Revise ya bastante la verdad, y inclusive hice un System.out.println y me sale bien los datos

Comment: El código en las preguntas va como texto; nadie te va a responder con imágenes.

Comment: @Alfabravo ya lo cambie ahora

Comment: @VictorAvila Bueno lo unico que se me ocurre que pueda ser es que el metodo RemoveAllItems() no este limpiando los items de la lista, prueba asignandolo a null

Comment: No se ve dónde inicializas `tipoUs`. Si lo limpiaras (o instanciaras) en cada iteración del resultSet, estaríás más seguro de lo que estás añadiendo a la lista.

Comment: Solo usas 1 tipoUs No lo inicializas, por ende solo tienes 1 objeto referenciado en un list 2 veces. Como menciona Alfabravo, si inicializas tipoUs dentro del while, traerás tantos objetos como encuentres en base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alfabravo y Ajeno lo solucione, inicialize dentro del while y ahora ya me viene todos los datos, les agradezco mucho enserio.

Comment: Que bien! Te sugiero poner tu solución como Respuesta en Tu Respuesta, con eso otros usuarios veran la solución.